# Is there a relative version of Tannakian reconstruction?

Tags: monoidal-categories, hopf-algebras

According to some form of Tannakian reconstruction, given a finite tensor category with a fiber functor to the category of vector spaces, one determines a Hopf algebra by considering tensor endomorphisms of the fiber functor.  As far as I know, a similar procedure is used to reconstruct a group from its symmetric tensor category of representations.

I am curious about what happens if one is given a finite tensor category $\mathcal{C}$ and a tensor functor $\mathcal{C} \to Rep(G)$ for $G$ a finite group.  It follows that there should exist a Hopf algebra $H$ (by the previous reconstruction business applied to the composition of this tensor functor with the forgetful functor $Rep(G) \to \mathrm{Vect}$) and homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[G] \to H$.

> Under what conditions will $H$ be a
>   semidirect product of $G$ with some Hopf algebra?

Comment: Does it follow that $\mathcal{C}G$ is a Hopf subalgebra of H? I guess one should impose additional properties on the tensor functor $\mathcal{C} \to Rep(G)$  to get an inclusion of Hopf algebras.

Comment: Let $F: Rep(G') \to Rep(G)$ be an exact tensor functor. It corresponds to a morphism of affine group schemes $\phi: G\to G'$. Then $\phi$ is a closed immersion iff every object of $Rep(G)$ is a subquotient of an objet in the image of $F$. And $\phi$ is surjective and flat iff $F$ is fully faithfull and its image is stable by taking subobjects. See Deligne, Milne - Tannakian categories.   

  

Comment: @Sebastian: I agree with you (I only said a homomorphism).

Comment: @YBL: Thanks! <present text added to reach 15 characters>

Comment: In the case of Hopf algebras, probably the same condition mentioned by YBL is necessary and sufficient to get an inclusion, although I didn't check that. 




Comment: A little more general question than the present one would be under what conditions on F one gets $\mathbb{C}G$ as a normal Hopf subalgebra of H? Then of course under these conditions it follows that H is a "byproduct" between $\mathbb{C}G$ and the corresponding quotient Hopf algebra.

@YBL In the affine group scheme settings is it known when $G$ is a normal subsecheme of $G'$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Akhil,

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a tensor category, and let $(A,\mu) \in \mathcal{C}-Alg$ be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}$.  So $\mu:A\otimes A\to A$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ and $\otimes$ here means the $\otimes$ in $\mathcal{C}$ (of course there isn't another one around at this point, but I mean to emphasize it's not just the $\otimes$ of Vect).

In this context, it makes sense to talk about $A$-modules in $\mathcal{C}$, whose definition you can guess.  These form a k-linear abelian category $D$ with a forgetful functor to $\mathcal{C}$ which forgets the $A$ action.

Now if $\mathcal{C}$ has a fiber functor F, then $\mathcal{C}$ is realized as the Hopf algebra $End(F)$, as you said (well $End(F)^{op}$ I think , but nevermind).  The algebra $A$ can be pushed forward by $F$ to an ordinary algebra $F(A)$ in Vect.  However, $D$ is not the category of $A$-modules, but a well-known proposition tells that $D$ is the category of $A\rtimes H$-modules, the semi-direct product you asked about.

Notice that no part of the discussion so far asked for any symmetric structure on $\mathcal{C}$, and also $A$ is only an algebra.  To define a bialgebra in $\mathcal{C}$, however, one needs $\mathcal{C}$ to be braided, because the compatibility between $\Delta$ and $\mu$ will use the braiding.  In your case braiding just means symmetry.  I never worked this out in detail, but I imagine that if $A$ is actually a bi-algebra in $\mathcal{C}$, then $D$ gets endowed with a monoidal structure, and that $D$ is the category of $A\rtimes H$-modules, where $A\rtimes H$ is a bi-algebra.  Likewise if $A$ is Hopf in $\mathcal{C}$, then $D$ is tensor and $A\rtimes H$ is a Hopf algebra, and $D\cong A \rtimes H$-mod.

---

Thus ends the part where I'm pretty sure I'm not saying anything too incorrect.  Below I will try to answer your actual question.  I would not trust it though until somebody smarter agrees with it.

---

So, now your question becomes (let's revert to considering algebras at the top and not Hopf algebras, since it should be clear how to extend):  Given a functor $F:D\to \mathcal{C}$, when is $F$ the forgetful functor corresponding to some algebra $A \in \mathcal{C}$?  I think for this, it will be enough to assume (in addition, of course, to assuming that $F$ is faithful and exact) that $D$ has a projective generator $M$ (although maybe this is guaranteed by a lesser assumption?).  This is definitely necessary to be able to realize $D$ as some category of modules of a ring, as you desire, and I imagine that you then let $A=\underline{Hom}(M,M)$ (meaning $\mathcal{C}$-internal homs, which are distinct from $Hom_\mathcal{C}(M,M)$!), which will be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}$, and you can plug into the above.

You should definitely read Ostrik's http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139 and other papers by Etingof, Nikshych, and Ostrik about fusion and finite tensor categories.

Comment: David, thanks for a great answer!  I looked at the paper by Ostrik in part (I will need a bit more time since I know very little about tensor categories in general), but do you mean $H \rtimes A$ instead of $A \rtimes H$?  I don't see how to get the action of $A$ on $H$.

Comment: Akhil, You're right that the Hopf algebra H acts on A, not vice versa.  Unfortunately, there are two conventions for the symbol $\rtimes$.  The one I have used is the one which generalizes a common usage for groups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product, so that the $\triangleleft$ points towards the normal subgroup.  This is also what Majid uses in his textbooks about Hopf algebras, I think.  But you're right that many authors use the opposite convention.  Oh well... =]

Comment: Another good source about this is Majid: Foundations of quantum group theory, Chapter 9.4.2 braided reconstruction. The basic assumption is that the functor $V\mapsto Nat(V\otimes F,F)$ for a fibre functor $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{B}$ is representable. The representing object will serve as an algebra, and given more structure on $\mathcal{C}$ preserved by $F$, it will have more structure. Namely, if $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal, it is a bialgebra; if $\mathcal{C}$ has duals, a Hopf algebra object in the category $\mathcal{V}$. This is in some sense an application of the Barr-Beck Theorem.

Comment: There is in general a factorization of $F$ through  $B$-Mod$(\mathcal{V})\to \mathcal{V}$ but this doesn't need to be an equivalence.